# different number of tables from user_tables and user_objects query

Tags: sql, oracle, data-dictionary

under the same schema, I got different number of tables from the following two queries:

```
select object_type,count(*) from user_objects group by object_type;
```

output: i got 17 for table from object_type column.

another query:

```
select count(*) from user_tables;
```

output:

> 13 rows selected.

Can someone tell me why I got two different numbers?

Comment: We would have to see your data to help you further.

Comment: I ran your queries across 4 different schemas and got consistent results each time. And the count was of the order of 1000s and still accurate to the dot. Yours seems to be a special case, so please provide additional data.

Comment: Don't say, SHOW and PROVE.We don't have your tables, so understand. SQL*Plus, copy and paste are your friend.

Comment: I checked `sys` user and searched tables in `user_objects` that are not in `user_tables`. I got `KOT%$` tables, `S_PROPS_TAB`, `PROPERTIES_TAB`, `USR_PROPERTIES_TAB`,`SCHEDULER%` tables and many `SYSNT%` tables. On "normal" schemas both counts were the same.

Answer (score -1):

Result of first query includes objects that are in BIN.
Try

```
select object_type,count(*) from user_objects where object_name not like 'BIN%' group by object_type;
```

You should get the same result

Comment: It will be an assumption till OP shows the table_names. If OP dropped those tables using PURGE, they shouldn't show up.

Comment: But why do you suggest my answer doesn't resolve the problem? I've checked it on a few schemas and the only difference between results I got on tables that are in the BIN. I suppose the queries from the question are run on typical users, not SYS not SYSTEM etc.

Comment: I am not saying your answer is incorrect, but the question itself lacks information. As I said, the recycle_bin objects won't show up in user_objects if they were purged during DROP.  So, your post is more of a comment than an answer at this stage. If you answer an incomplete question, you will end up with an incomplete answer ;-)

Comment: I agree that PURGE removes objects from the BIN but in that case both queries should give the same result. I cannot find any other reason for this difference. Would be nice if the author of the question said something...

Comment: That's what I said earlier, we are yet to see OP to provide the relevant information. And just in case if you are not aware, STACK OVERFLOW is NOT a forum to discuss over issues with assumptions. All the suggestions are appropriate for comments section. Neither am I saying that you are incorrect, nor did I vote down your answer, in case if you are contemplating if I have voted down. As I would certainly provide a reason as an etiquette :-)

Comment: Your statement `I agree that PURGE removes objects from the BIN but in that case both queries should give the same result` is wrong. Think again.

Comment: That's the reason how would you see those purged tables in the view you are referring to? You can add a test case in your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61120/discussion-between-pawel-kowalski-and-lalit-kumar-b).